# googlemaps returning list instead of dict

Tags: python, google-maps

I'm relative new to Python, so I hope this question is not too stupid. 
I have several coordinates (latitudes and longitudes) and I want to compute the driving distance and time using the Google Maps API. I'm following the code in http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net/

For now, I'm trying only one pair of origin-destination. Here is my code:

```
    import os
    import csv
    from googlemaps import Client

    ## Working directory
    wdir = 'mydir'
    os.chdir(wdir)

    ## Import data
    rowsarray=[]

    with open(os.path.relpath("Data/geocodes.csv"), "rb") as csvfile:
         reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
         for row in reader:
            rowsarray.append(row)

    ## Google Maps
    gmaps = Client('mykey')        

    origin = float(rowsarray[1][0]),float(rowsarray[1][1])
    destination = float(rowsarray[1][2]),float(rowsarray[1][3])

    dirs = gmaps.directions(origin, destination)
    time = dirs['Directions']['Duration']['seconds']
    distance = dirs['Directions']['Distance']['meters']
```

My problem is that I cannot recover the time and distance. The error I get is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I don't know why, but the object 'dirs' is a list and not a dict. I believe there is something really simple that I'm missing, but I can't figure out what it is.
Just for the reference, I believe origin and destination are in the correct format, for example:

```
    origin
    (-23.9592578, -46.3744664)
    destination
    (-23.6605557, -47.2263173)
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: If you use `print dirs` instead of the last two lines, what do you get? Most probably, `dirs['Directions']` is a sequence containing lot of "directions", whatever format each `direction` may have. You might want to inspect `dirs` for that.

Comment: Also, this API is rather old, you might prefer to use the REST api with `urllib`, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API is rather old, you might prefer to use the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?#JSON) like this:

```
import json
import urllib

origin = (-30.2664935,-51.8364501)
destination = (-30, -51)

geocode_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={[lat]},{[lon]}&sensor=false'
directions_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=false&origin={}&destination={}'

distance = 0;
duration = 0;

pars = (origin, destination)
request_url = directions_url.format(*pars)
result_string = urllib.urlopen(request_url).read();
result = json.loads(result_string)
if result['status'] == "OK":
    routes = result['routes']
    for route in routes:
        legs = route['legs']
        for leg in legs:
            distance += leg['distance']['value']
            duration += leg['duration']['value']

print distance, duration
```

Comment: Thank you so much @heltonbiker! I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use the googlemaps python module, try the following:

```
print dirs[0]['Duration']['seconds']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object dirs is a list that contains one item, which is the dict you seek.

```
type(dirs) # returns type 'list'
type(mapresults[0]) # returns type 'dict'
tot_drive_time = dirs[0]['legs'][0]['duration']['value']
tot_distance = dirs[0]['legs'][0]['distance']['value']
```

FYI, the module googlemaps 2.4.2 was last updated 2015-12-03